# Insert data into the database from another android application

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Insert the data to the current application database from the another application database. Any example?

Comment: Consider implementing your own ContentProvider in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest two ways that you can achieve this.

1. You can save the database in the external storage and access it from there. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).
2. You can save the database in the internal application storage and access it with [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

**EDIT** I suggest the second way using content providers since it is the recommended way and it is also more safe. If you save your database to your external storage the user can access and modify it and that can cause troubles.

Comment: You cannot save database on External Storage!!

Comment: I have already created an app that can save the database in the external storage, so yes it can be done. It is not safe to do so but it is not impossible. Keep in mind  that a database is just a file so it is possible to move that file from your app's internal storage to the external storage.

Comment: But i'did have idea how to call the other application using content provider. Thank you for your answer.